# Fzf.vim does not work due to fzf missing programs

Tags: plugins, lua, neovim, vim-fzf

In OS X, I load the fzf.vim plugin using the command

`call minpac#add('junegunn/fzf.vim')`

without any subsequent configuration. The Find, Buffer, etc., commands are not executed because Neovim can't find the fzf functions.

Fzf has been installed with Brew and is working correctly in the Fish shell.

I'm seeking assistance to properly configure the plugin using Lua.

Thank you for any contributions.

Comment: `call minpac#update()`

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't change the outcome.I did more: I emptied ~/config/nvim and reinstalled everything, but the same error persists.

Comment: It seems like the plugin code is unable to correctly invoke FZF programs installed with Brew (available and functional in the Fish shell running in the terminal).

Comment: Check that `fzf` is in `PATH`.

Comment: Yes, it is but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't realized that it was necessary to install fzf.vim as well.